# how to call a javascript function on radio button's 'checked' property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have N number of radio button groups in the page with auto generated names.

I want to call a javascript function as the value of the checked property.  **THIS LINE EXCLUDED AFTER EDIT** ( Depending on the return value, the radio button needs to  be checked or unchecked.)

```
<input type="radio" name="auto_generated_name" value="some_value" checked="test_check(args);" />
```

and the javascript function is

```
function test_check(params) {
    if(conditions){
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;    
}
```

But that does not work. Whatever value I assign to 'checked' property, be it any javascript function or any string etc, the radio button becomes checked.

How can I achieve my goal?

EDIT:

```
 <input type="radio" name="auto_generated_name" value="somevalue" onclick="test_check(args)"/>
```

4 radio buttons make a group. such N radio groups have html class names in this way :  button_group_1, button_group_2, button_group_3, button_group_4 etc.

The 'args' need to be these class (i.e. radio button group) names and the corresponding values (from value="1", value="2", value="3" and value="4" ).

Cookies with the class names and values will be created inside the javascript function.

On page refresh, cookies matching with the class names will be checked and depending on the existence of the corresponding cookies, the radio button will be checked or unchecked.

How to achieve the goals/

Comment: trying to accept satisfactory answers. args contains the name of radio button group so that from within the javascript function i can create a cookie with the name of args and a value equal to 1.

Comment: do you want to control change event with "test_check(args);" am i right ? i mean when try to checked it you need to call test_check(args); function?

Comment: @erimerturk , when the page is loading, checked="test_check(args)" will trigger the javascript function. If the return value of the function is true, radion button will be checked, if return value is false, it won't be checked. If assigning a js function to 'checked' property is not the expected way, what should be the way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jQuery, use the change event: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Do u notice that there are N number of radio buttin groups ? N has no fixed value. Depending on the situation the page will have variable number of radio button groups..

Comment: Specify a particular class name for all the active radio buttons and use that as the selector.

Comment: What are you passing in the args? Is it related to that particular input?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Here I user a custom attribute to `input` named `groupname`. In OP's case `groupname="<?php echo $radio_button_group_name; ?>"`. Then checking the value of this attribute OP can assign `checked` attribute value.

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" groupname="gr1"/>
<input type="radio" name="r2" groupname="gr2"/>

$('input:radio').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('groupname') == 'gr1') {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed this will check for each `radio` where it is checked or not

Comment: OP is asking to set the checked attribute of the radio button, not check it.

Comment: @abdullah.abcoder, would u please make ur reply easier to understand?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan , OP?  can't understand your comment

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed - OP is short for YOU the poster :)

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` attribute is simply a boolean value to indicate whether the radio button should be checked, it cannot contain script, or a reference to a scripting function. Any value in the attribute will cause the radio button to be checked.

Without knowing what mechanism you are using to check each radio button - I can see an `args` variable but don't know what type this is - it's going to be tricky to write some code for you.

If you can make `args` into an array of values, then something along the lines of the following should work for you:

```
var args = new Array(true,false,true)

$.each(args, function(index, value) {
    $("INPUT[type=radio]").eq(index).attr("checked", value)
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ftsd2/) to show what I mean more clearly

Comment: suppose no 'args' and 'params' exist.

Comment: If no `args` or `params` exist then how are you supposed to know what to check?!?!

Comment: lol i said that just for the sake of clarity. args contains the name of radio button group so that from within the javascript function i can create a cookie with the name of args and a value equal to 1. class names are auto generated. if the serial number of the question is k, class name is class_k . This nomenclature is done with php and php variable will be assigned to args. Actually instead of assigning any value to args, i will call the function  this way: test_check(<?php echo $radio_button_group_name; ?>).

Comment: any more clarification? SEE MY EDIT

Answer (score 0):

check this output, valid args is 'aa'.

http://jsfiddle.net/X7rcC/1

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="auto_generated_name" value="some_value1" checked="bb" />
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    var radios = $("input[type='radio']");
    $.each(radios, function(index, value){
        var args = value.attributes[1].nodeValue;
       test_check(args, value);
    })

});

function test_check(params, value){

    if(params == "aa"){
     $(value).attr("checked",true);
    }else
     $(value).attr("checked",false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `checked` attribute this way, because anything as the value will be the same as `checked=true` Even just `checked` checks a radio button. What you should do is use a custom attribute which will create the checked attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="auto_generated_name" value="some_value" needs_check="param">

<script>
  // Do test_check on param for each input
  $('input:radio').each(function()
  {
    var radio = $(this);
    var param = radio.attr('needs_check');

    var condition = test_check(param);

    radio.attr('checked', condition);    
  });

  function test_check(param)
  {
    return true or false based on param
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ur html is for radio button and the js is for checkbox.. mistake I think.. but when will the javascript code execute? on the first time of loading the page? When the user interacts with the radio buttons randomly, will the js code execute?

Comment: When the page is loaded, like you wanted

Comment: i did not mention that I  want only the load-time functionality. I need those on page refresh as well. See the edit please

Comment: Page refresh is also a page load event. You can do the cookie validation in test_check and it will check / uncheck the radio buttons. (edited answer a bit since you wanted radio buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question really boils down to:

> How can I set the value of a checkbox when the page first loads? (Using a parameter stored with the checkbox)

The key insights are:

- you can't store a function inside a parameter and expect it to automatically evaluate on load
- you can store the data about an object inside `data-` properties
- you can set the value of objects on page load in jQuery using the $(document).ready() event

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {                    // this code runs when the page is first loaded
   var radios = $("input[type='radio']");          // find all of your radio buttons
    $.each(radios, function(){
       var radio = $(this);
       var param = radio.attr('data-param');       // retrieve the param from the object
       radio.attr('checked', test_check(param) );  // set the value of the radio button
    })
});

function test_check(params) {
    if(conditions){
        return 'checked';
    }
    else 
        return '';    
}
</script>
```

Comment: ur answer seems to be the same as that of Tessmore. I need to execute the js function whenever the user has an interaction with the radio buttons.. And I was talking about radio buttons, not checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and my conclusion is that don't use " " to contain a function.

Correct:

```
<input type="radio" name="im" id="b1" onclick=alert("hello"); />
```

Incorrect:

```
<input type="radio" name="im" id="b1" onclick="alert("hello");" />
```